# How to record audio and get the result as Uint8List?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've recently started to learn about audio and how it works in a low level. And for a project I'm building, I'm required to have a recorded audio as a `Uint8List`. I've searched far and wide for plugins that give audio as Uint8List, but I've found none. So are there any packages that returns the recorded audio as a Uint8List? Or is there any way that allows conversion of a recorded audio into Uint8List? Thanks!

Comment: [Flutter Sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) may be what you are looking for. It also has some [utility functions](https://flutter-sound.canardoux.xyz/tau_api_utilities_pcm_to_wave_buffer.html) to convert waves and pcms into buffers

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your recorded audio file , you can read it as `Uint8List`.

```
Uint8List uint8list = Uint8List.fromList(File(myaudioPath).readAsBytesSync())
```